# Axiomatizing naturals

Tags: logic, theorem-proving

Trying to implement the naturals in Mathematica, I follow E. Mendelson, Introduction to Mathematical Logic, Ch. 3, Par. 1.
Here is my code for the axioms (exept the induction axiom)

```
Naxioms = {ForAll[{x, y, z},   Implies[x == y, Implies[x == z, y == z]]], 
ForAll[{x, y}, Implies[x == y, next[x] == next[y]]], 
ForAll[x, zero != next[x]],  ForAll[{x, y}, Implies[next[x] == next[y], x == y]], 
ForAll[x, plus[x, zero] == x],ForAll[{x, y}, plus[x, next[y]] == next[plus[x, y]]], 
ForAll[x, mul[x, zero] == zero],ForAll[{x, y}, mul[x, next[y]] == plus[mul[x, y], next[x]]]};
```

However, I fail with it, proving a simple theorem

```
FindEquationalProof[ForAll[x, plus[zero, x] == x], Naxioms]
```

> FindEquationalProof::invs: Invalid specification of propositions !(*SubscriptBox[([ForAll]), ({x})](plus[zero, x] == x)) and axioms {!(*SubscriptBox[([ForAll]), ({x, y, z})]((x == y [Implies] ((x == z [Implies] y == z))))),!(*SubscriptBox[([ForAll]), ({x, y})]((x == y [Implies] next[x] == next[y]))),<<5>>,!(*SubscriptBox[([ForAll]), ({x, y})](mul[x, next[y]] == plus[mul[x, y], next[x]]))}

and the returned input. The questions arise: what is the reason? how to fix it? how to formulate the induction axiom?

Comment: I would recommend starting from just two basic axioms and gradually introducing the others to find the bad ones: `Naxioms = {
   ForAll[{x, y}, plus[x, y] == plus[y, x]],
   ForAll[x, plus[x, zero] == x]
   };` works.

Comment: The problem appears to be that Mathematica doesn't think that the first 4 axioms are proper equations. You can check like this (I found this internal function via tracing) ```Language`EquationalProofDump`isEquationQ /@ Naxioms``` returns `{False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True}`

Comment: @flinty: I think E, Mendelson has solid reasons to formulate his axiomatics as it is. Thank you for the second comment of you. Does this mean that `FindEquationalProof` currently deals with `==`, but not with `Implies` and `!=`?

Comment: I'm not sure, it seems to be quite fussy about what it thinks is a valid equation: see here: https://pastebin.com/LsrdCt3P Something must go wrong internally - I suspect `FindEquationalProof` is kind of broken for a lot of use cases like yours, unless there are subtle semantics of `ForAll` that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @flinty: Thank you again. Can you kindly  give an answer based on the  [link](https://pastebin.com/LsrdCt3P)? If the state of affairs is as you describe, then `FindEquationalProof` is not a strong command.

Comment: I'm not certain enough to give a full answer as I've only used this feature a few times _(and I've always had difficulty with anything non-trivial and not in the docs)_. Also there's probably no hope for the induction axiom as it's a second order axiom, and it appears `FindEquationalProof` seems to suit first-order logic only. For example you cannot do second-order problems quantified over propositions like: `FindEquationalProof[Exists[X, X[0]], {P[0], Q[0]}]` expecting to get `P[0]` or `Q[0]` unifying `X` with `P` or `Q`. You may want to try Prolog, TLA+, z3, Lean theorem prover, perhaps.

Comment: @flinty: I am sure your answer based on the link and your comments would be useful not only for me. In any case, many thanks from me to you. It is kind of you.

Comment: When using the equationsl proofs, you generally also have to implement the proofs of multiplication...i believe that may be missing in your code...there is mention of this in the docs.

Comment: @morbo: If you mean the axioms, these are taken from E.Mendelson, Introduction to Masthematical Logic. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494 by the way, I have a feeling Mathematica might be using this theorem prover: https://webwaldmeister.waldmeister.org for proof finding in some places, because 'waldmeister' appears in the traces as ```Language`EquationalProofDump`waldmeister```.  Also check here: https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/automation-of-logic/software/waldmeister/ _...Stephen Wolfram has employed our system to carry out investigations in the area of singleton axiom systems for Boolean algebra..._ . So it wouldn't surprise me if that's being used as part of `FindEquationalProof`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a first draft of an answer.

Induction will be used as the proof technique. Since Mathematica uses an equational prover, there's no direct way to use induction. What will be ventured here are just two first-order proofs, one for the basis case and the other for the induction step.

```
axioms = {
  ForAll[x, plus[x, zero] == x],
  ForAll[{x, y}, plus[x, next[y]] == next[plus[x, y]]]}
```

Basis case:

```
FindEquationalProof[ForAll[x, plus[zero, zero] == zero], axioms]
```

Induction assumption:

```
assertion = {ForAll[x, plus[zero, x] == x]}
```

Induction step:

```
FindEquationalProof[ForAll[x, plus[zero, next[x]] == next[x]], 
 Union[axioms, assertion]]
```

EDIT: As requested in the comments, the following is a proof of $2+2=4$. The axioms are the same as above:

```
FindEquationalProof[
 plus[next[next[zero]], next[next[zero]]] == 
  next[next[next[next[zero]]]], axioms]
```

Comment: Can you prove $2+2=4$ ( maybe, extending your `axioms`)? TIA.

Comment: @user64494: The proof of $2+2=4$ has been added as an edit to the original answer.

Comment: ShyPerson(@ does not work.)^ Thank you. I need some time to think about it.