# Prove a relation involving Floor holds for arbitrary $n$

Tags: forall

The 1968 International Mathematical Olympiad asks contestants to prove this relation involving the floor function for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\left\lfloor \frac{n + 2^0}{2^1} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n + 2^1}{2^2} \right\rfloor + \cdots + \left\lfloor \frac{n + 2^{n-1}}{2^n} \right\rfloor = n$$

I can create a function that computes the expression on the left-hand-side:

```
f[n_Integer] := Total[Table[Floor[(n + 2^(i - 1))/2^i], {i, n}]];
```

and easily test that the equation holds for any $n$ I happen to choose, e.g.,

```
f[531] == 531
```

(* True *)

But of course this is not a proof for arbitrary $n$.

I've tried `Resolve`, `Simplify`, `Solve`, and related operations for the left-hand-side, but the key problem is that these can operate only when the summation limit is specified with a particular value of $n$--not in the general case.

How to prove (or demonstrate) this relation computationally in the case of arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Does using `Quotient[n, k]` in place of `Floor[n/k]` (since these are equivalent) help?

Comment: No.... and I don't see why such a replacement would, as the central problem remains of needing to specify the upper limit on the sum.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Mathematica would need to have some known equational relation (a stepping stone if you will) added to it to transform the sum into a form that ultimately reduces to $n$. Mathematica cannot 'prove' this by induction with something like `FindEquationalProof` - [see my comments and the answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/245304/72682)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Main identity

As you can see from the linked youtube video, the solution is based on the fact that the sum is in fact a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). In turn, it relies on the following remarkable property

$$\lfloor nx\rfloor=\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \left\lfloor \frac{k}{n}+x\right\rfloor \tag{1},$$
where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

### Proof of Eq.(1) using Mathematica

With a little assistance, MA can prove this identity for *fixed* values of $n$. This is completely sufficient for our needs. Define a general function

```
g[x_, n_] := Sum[Floor[x + k/n], {k, 0, n - 1}] - Floor[n x]
```

Now consider the case $n=2$ as needed for the problem:

```
FullSimplify[g[x, 2], Assumptions -> 0 <= x < 1/2]
(* 0 *)
```

Notice, that we proved the identity (1) on a small interval. Complementing it with a proof of periodicity

```
FullSimplify[g[x + 1/2, 2] - g[x, 2]]
(* 0 *)
```

we establish that `g[x,2]==0`.

- From here the OP identity follows using the telescopic property.

### Generalization

Analogously one can establish the identity for other values of $n$. For instance, for $n=3$ we have
$$\sum _{i=1}^n \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n+3^{i-1}}{3^i}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{n+2\cdot 3^{i-1}}{3^i}\right\rfloor \right)=n\tag{2}$$

or in MA language:

```
f3[n_Integer] := Sum[Floor[(n + 3^(i - 1))/3^i] + Floor[(n + 2 3^(i - 1))/3^i], {i, n}];
f3[531]
(* 531 *)
```

### The telescoping sum

For completeness I present here the connection between the equation in the OP and the identity Eq.(1). For a better explanation see the [youtube video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=cHk8ML8dcoY). For $n=2$, from Eq.(1) that we proved with the help of Mathematica we have
$$\small
\left\lfloor
x+\frac12 
\right\rfloor=
\left\lfloor2x 
\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor x 
\right\rfloor.
$$
Now, use it in every term of the original identity
$$\small \left\lfloor \frac{n + 2^0}{2^1} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n + 2^1}{2^2} \right\rfloor + \cdots + \left\lfloor \frac{n + 2^{n-1}}{2^n} \right\rfloor
=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^1} +\frac12 \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n }{2^2} +\frac12 \right\rfloor + \cdots + \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^n} +\frac12 \right\rfloor\\
=\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^0}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^1}\right\rfloor\right)+
\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^1}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^2}\right\rfloor\right)+ \cdots +
\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^{n}}\right\rfloor\right)\\
=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^0}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^{n}}\right\rfloor=n.
$$
As can be seen, all terms except the first and the last ones cancel. QED

Comment: Casn you elborate "From here the OP identity follows using the telescopic property."? TIA.

Comment: yarchik(@ does not work.): Thank you. It ia too poor direction to me though I am PhD in math for ages. Also `Resolve[ForAll[n, 
  Floor[n/2^n + 1/2] == 
   Floor[n/2^(n - 1)] - Floor[n/2^n]], PositiveIntegers]` fails.

Comment: @user64494 It is *really unbelievable* that MA can prove the identity (1), albeit with a little intervention of a human and for fixed values of $n$. To me this was completely unexpected. It shows that one really gets nice answers provided the questions are properly formulated. Of course, one can always obfuscate the problem that even human will have a difficulty. Mathematics olympiads are known for such obfuscations. They have little in common with the research work.

Comment: The telescoping sum is done by hand.. However,+1.

Comment: @yarchik:  Excellent work, requiring knowledge of math *and* *Mathematica*, showing its power is far beyond the mere button pushing of translating a problem directly into code.  Someday versions of *Mathematica* will include more such "human insight" and it is this kind of solution that shows what is needed.  ($\checkmark$)

Comment: @yarchik:  The only improvement I could recommend is using *Mathematica* to perform the substitution and cancellation in your last equation.

Answer (score -1):

How about it?

```
FindSequenceFunction[Table[Total[Table[Floor[(n + 2^(i - 1))/2^i], {i, n}]],{n, 1, 4}], n]
```

> `n`

Addition. Another approach is as follows.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; NMaximize[{(Sum[Floor[(n + 2^(i - 1))/2^i], {i, n}] - n)^2, 
n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}, n, Method -> DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> `{0., {n -> 20}}`

Comment: Thanks and... almost, but not quite.  You've only shown that the sequence of the four first terms can be fit by the monomial $n$.  It is a matter of faith—not proof—that the sequence is valid for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: You may replace `4` by `4*10^2` or try to mimic with Mathematica a proof by hand.

Comment: Well, just as the extraordinarily high tests of the Collatz Conjecture do not prove it, so too your $4 \cdot 10^2$ doesn't come close to a "proof," and *certainly* doesn't mimic the solution by hand here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHk8ML8dcoY

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: At the present and in the near future Mathematica  cannot do tricky proofs of unusual identities  with `Floor`. That's life. All the best.

Comment: I have done a few proofs with Floor, but this one is a bit tricky.  My approach was to prove by induction using *Mathematica*:  Show that if the relation holds for $n$ then it holds for $n+1$.  I still think that is the way to go... using `Solve` or some related function to that end.  Back to work for me!

Comment: Can the downvoter explain the downvote? TIA.